# want to replace image if no image available in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

If I need change image dynamically.how I need to adjust the below code to perform replacement but it does not works?
hers is my code:

```
htmlContent+="<img src='"+response[i].userImageUrl+"' class='round-avatar
overlapIcon' onerror='this.src='resources/images/userImg.jpg''>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: you have a problem with your quotes - try `onerror='this.src=\'resources/images/userImg.jpg\''`

Comment: htmlContent+="<img src='"+userimage+"' onerror='this.src='images.jpg''>

Comment: yes how can i do it in htmlcontent+= please provide me some solutions

Comment: I showed you, if you don't understand escaping `\'` then try to find a beginners course in javascript

Comment: how can i add a {pagecontext.request.contextpath} in that

Comment: not working can you provide me some other solutions